# why i'm not receiving values in server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, formik

```
    const SignUpForm = () => {
   const {values ,errors , handleChange , handleSubmit} = useFormik({
    initialValues ,
    validationSchema: SignupSchema,
    onSubmit : async ()=>{
        const user = await  fetch('http://localhost:8080/user/register' ,{
       method : "POST" ,
       body : JSON.stringify(values)
     })
     console.log(user ,values);
    }
})



   
 const router = express.Router()
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}))
router.use(express.json())

router.post('/register' , async(req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.body);
        res.json({
                message : 'success'
        })
})
```

I am trying to get form values in server , but it's returning me an empty object. is there any issue with post request? . I have tried everything I know but its not working  .

Comment: Please, copy paste your code and click `{}` to mark it as code.

Comment: I've pasted the code .

Answer (score 0):

please do the below change and check

Write below code:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Instead of

```
router.use(express.json())
```

Comment: Since they don't show any server code, this is a WILD guess.  Answers should not be wild guesses here.  The OP should be required to write a clear question that does not require guessing.

Comment: Actually there is screenshot attached with the code, please look at the top

Comment: @kruthal - Code does NOT belong in screenshots here on stackoverflow.  It can't be searched for.  It can't be copy pasted into answers.  It sucks on mobile.  Your code MUST be pasted into the question as text and formatted as code - that's how it works here.  Code in images is prohibited here.  You can easily use the "edit" link below your question to fix it.

Comment: sorry my bad . I added code instead of images

Comment: @KrunalJethi brother your solution is not working already tried.

Answer (score 0):

@KASHi Try below code :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
app.use(express.json())    // <==== parse request body as JSON

// Single routing
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Router Working");
    res.end();
})
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(" POST Router Working",req.body);
    res.end();
})

app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```

I tried above It's working. compare with your code, if still not works then paste your whole server js file here so I can help

Comment: thanks brother . I've already solved the problem .